# How to find values based on pattern matching from 2 string

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have string

```
a = "{key1}|{key2}_{key3}-{key4}"
```

I have another string

```
b = "abc|qwe_tue-pqr"
```

I need the output to be as to get values of

```
key1="abc", key2="qwe", key3="tue" and key4="pqr"
```

Comment: If the case is more complex than that, regex would be happy to eat this; have you taken a look at it? If it's that simple then Split would do.. Can you post, say, 5 other variations of `a` you might see used?

Comment: the delimitter can be anything which is not predefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the use case is as simple as presented you could perhaps transform `a` into a regex with named capturing groups:

```
var r = new Regex(Regex.Escape(a).Replace("\\{","(?<").Replace("}",">[a-z]+)"));
```

This turns `a` into a regex like (the | delimiter needed escaping):

```
(?<key1>[a-z]+)\|(?<key2>[a-z]+)_(?<key3>[a-z]+)-(?<key4>[a-z]+)
```

You can then get the matches and print them:

```
var m = r.Match(b);
foreach(Group g in m.Groups){
  Console.WriteLine(g.Name + "=" + g.Value);
}
```

```
key1=abc
key2=qwe
key3=tue
key4=pqr
```

I can't promise it will reliably process everything you throw into it, based on the very limited input example, but it should give you the idea for a start on the process